# Sleep and Join output in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, join, sleep

Two code blocks for Join and Sleep. Have trouble identifying why output is coming as 5,5,5 for all 3 threads, then 4,4,4 , then 3,3,3 and so on. Instead with join it should first wait for 1st thread to finish and then again print 5,4,3,2,1.

```
public class DemoJoin {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
        NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("Two");
        NewThread ob3 = new NewThread("Three");
        /*System.out.println("Thread One is alive: "
                + ob1.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: "
                + ob2.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: "
                + ob3.t.isAlive());*/
        // wait for threads to finish
        try {
System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
ob1.t.join();

ob2.t.join();
ob3.t.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
}
        System.out.println("Thread One is alive: "
                + ob1.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: "
                + ob2.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: "
                + ob3.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
    }
}
```

Thread Class:

```
package com.demo.test;


public class NewThread implements Runnable {
    String name; // name of thread
    Thread t;
    NewThread(String threadname) {
        name = threadname;
        t = new Thread(this, name);

        System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
        t.start(); // Start the thread
    }
    // This is the entry point for thread.
    public void run() {
        try {
            for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
    }
}
```

Issue is if I sleep is uncommented, I get 5,5,5 from all 3 threads and then 4,4,4 and so on.

But with Join, second thread should wait for 1st thread to finish. i.e. my output should be 5,4,3,2,1 from first thread and then again 5,4,3,2,1 from second thread.

If I uncomment sleep, then I get the exact output.

I want to understand why sleep is causing all 3 threads to execute simulatenously even with join present.

Comment: I *never* understand these questions. If you want a specific order of execution, why are you using threads?

Comment: It's not about the order. It's about understanding why including sleep is making a difference.

Comment: When your program executes `ob1.t.join()` it does not do _anything_ to the `ob1.t` thread.  The join method never does anything to any thread.  All it does is not return until the thread has finished.

Answer (score 2):

> But with Join, second thread should wait for 1st thread to finish

`join` does not serialize the thread execution between the three threads you've created, instead, `join`  will block the main thread until each of the created threads is complete, in the sequence `ob1`, `ob2`, `ob3`.

You've already started 3 background threads running (in the `NewClass` constructor), so parallel execution is already happening before the main thread hits the first `join`.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. ... `t.join();` causes the **current thread** to pause execution until t's thread terminates. *(emphasis mine)*

You actually have 4 threads here - main, and the three threads that you create.

Once started, the three threads will thus execute concurrently (hence the erratic ordering of the print output), and your main thread will block until all three are complete.

*Re:*

> If I uncomment sleep, then I get the exact output.

There is no guarantee here either - it just so happens that on your setup, without the 1 second sleep, that the first thread completes in entirety before the second thread begins its output. The output I get is:

```
One: 5
Waiting for threads to finish.
Two: 5
Two: 4
Two: 3
Three: 5
One: 4
One: 3
One: 2
One: 1
Three: 4
Two: 2
Two: 1
Two exiting.
Three: 3
One exiting.
Three: 2
Three: 1
```

Comment: But why if I comment sleep 1st thread print 5,4,3,2,1 and then second thread prints 5,4,3,2,1 and so on in order. With sleep uncommented, then the output order changes. Each thread prints 5 then 4 then 3 and so on. Why difference in the output because of sleep function.

Comment: I've updated. This is because on your setup, thread 1 completes before thread 2 gets going. On my i7 I get different results to you.

Comment: IMO there would be no point in creating 3 threads and then serializing their execution - the whole point of threading is to parallelize execution, and you then use join to synchronize (wait for the other threads to complete) before continuing with further work (which would usually be dependent on the work done by the other threads). Out of interest, you can also do more useful work on the main thread as well, after starting the 3 background threads, before using `join` to wait for the other threads to complete.

Comment: Well. I have no use of doing the same. I only intended to understand why including sleep was not working as expected. However, it seemed like now I understood. a bit confusion earlier but now its clear.